# unable to insert data into database from html

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I am trying to  insert  data from a html file into my database "customers"

I am however able to connect to database but unable to insert data from a [html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DS5r.png) file to my database

screenshot of [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZvLF.png)
    [image]
Notes:

1. I have not set password for phpmyadmin just the username as "root"
2. all files are stored in same folder (C:\wamp64\www)

**customers.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>customers</title>
</head>
<body>

  <center><form action="SignUp.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="customer id"><br>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="firstname"><br>
        <input type="text" name="orderno" placeholder="order no"> <br>
        <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="city"><br>
        <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="product price"><br>
        <button type="submit">order</button>
     </form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

**SignUp.php**

```
<?php

include 'db.php';

$sql= "INSERT INTO customers (id,firstname,orderno,city,price)
VALUES ('345','username','979','city','4465')";

 if($result=mysql_query($sql)==true)
        echo "data inserted successfully";
 else
        echo "failed to insert data";
?>
```

**db.php**

```
<?php

$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","customers");
if(!$conn){
        die("connection failed : " .mysqli_connect_error());
}
else{
        echo "connection created successfully"."<br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: You are combining `mysqli_*` functions with `mysql_` they are not the same.

Comment: Have you tried googling the messages? mysql_* is deprecated, so don't write code containing it, and do not mix mysql* and mysqli*. "Access denied" look like the access is not possible with the credentials you entered

Comment: I haven't set any credentials the password is empty and the username as "root'

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your issue but, Instead of `customers.html` you should make it `customers.php`, make your life a little easier, and also

This statement

```
<?php

include 'db.php';

$sql= "INSERT INTO customers (id,firstname,orderno,city,price)
VALUES ('345','username','979','city','4465')";

 if($result=mysql_query($sql)==true)
        echo "data inserted successfully";
 else
        echo "failed to insert data";
?>
```

should be

```
<?php

include 'db.php';

$sql= "INSERT INTO customers (id, firstname, orderno, city, price)
VALUES ('345','username','979','city','4465')";

 if($result=mysql_query($sql)==true) {
        echo "data inserted successfully";
 } else {
        echo "failed to insert data";
 }
?>
```

You did not include the brackets in your `if/else` code.

If you're going to be using mysqli to connect to the db you might as well transform your SignUp.php to

```
<?php
$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (id, firstname, orderno, city, price)
VALUES ('345', 'username', '979', 'city', '4465')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

[Also you might wanna take a look at this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

[As well as this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)